# Переход на HTML5

Tags: веб-программирование, html5

Кто уже перенёс свои сайты на **Html5**? Какие были подводные камни?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вряд ли вам кто-то что-то новое скажет. Массовый переход на html5 состоялся года два назад.
Поддержка старыми браузерами новых тэгов — да, вызывала сложности. Но решения появилисьь ещё тогда же и уже устоялись.
Новые технологии — ну тут всё понятно: поддержка браузерами — это не подводные камни, это просто то, что необходимо учитывать всегда.